# Concise description of Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, definition, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I would like to confirm that the following is an acceptable description of the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The outer Lebesgue measure $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$:

$$\lambda^{*}(E) = \inf\limits \{ ~\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \text{vol}(Q_{k}):~\{Q_{k}\}_{k} \text{ are rectangles covering } E \text{ such that } E \subset \bigcup_{k=0}Q_{k} \} $$

The following properties are satisfied:

- $\lambda^{*}(E) \geq 0 ~~~ \forall E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$
- $\lambda^{*}(\emptyset) = \lambda^{*}(\{x\}) = 0 ~~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
- If $E \subset F$ then, $\lambda^{*}(E) \leq \lambda^{*}(F)$

**Definition**:

A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if for every $F$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\lambda^{*}(F) = \lambda^{*}(E \cap F) + \lambda^{*}(F \setminus E)$$
Then we can let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the family of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Would you recommend any changes to this and are there recommendations of books/notes where the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is described in a good concise way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right ideas.  Presumably, $F$ should be any subset of $\Bbb R^n$; what you're describing there is [Carathéodory's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_criterion).  Also, I think you have some extra words in you definition of Lebesgue measure; I would write
$$
\lambda^{*}(E) = \inf\limits \{ ~\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \text{vol}(Q_{k}):~\{Q_{k}\}_{k} \text{ are rectangles such that } E \subset \bigcup_{k=0}Q_{k} \}
$$
Note that it doesn't make a difference if you define rectangles to be open or closed.

As for references: I would look through [Stroock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810201451).